# How do Mysql index process when a table have more index than one?

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing

Sample table

1. field 0 : no(PK)
2. field 1 : title
3. field 2 : description
4. field 3 : category1(INDEX)
5. field 4 : category2(INDEX)
6. field 5 : category3(INDEX)
7. field 6 : category4(INDEX)
8. field 7 : category5(INDEX)

Above is a sample that i will use on my website and category fields have an index each.

If i execute like this command below

```
select * from table where category1=1 and category2=2 and category3=3 and category4=4 and category5=5
```

To compare that a table have only one category field to that the table have a lot of category like above table. Which one is better?

I figured out that of course, a table which have only one category field is good choice. 
But i really don't know deep information about a calculation process of index.
I have to explain something different between them to my boss!!!!

So i want to get some information with a "sample" with index cost, sample data,  calculation process or other will be useful to understand about index calculation process

Comment: try EXPLAIN in front of SELECT and MySQL will explain you whats going on and which index is used for that query :o)

Comment: Why do you worry about performance if you are using completely wrong table design? If your table has 1:many relation to some categories, then you don't hardcode it into columns, you create another table that links your entity to its categories. THEN you can start worrying about performance, when the foundation is solid.

Comment: I also find it disappointing that so many answers will point the person towards `EXPLAIN` when there's apparent lack of knowledge of relational design.

Comment: Thanks!! All your answers!! First of all i will test a query using EXPLAIN and secondary, I will make a table so there will be three table. (1) contents_table, (2) contents_category_table, (3) static_category_table . and they are related each other. (1),(2) is related like this "1:N", (3),(2) is related like this "1:N" and after finished above test, i will comment a result of doing this job. Thank you guys!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you have query with more than one WHERE constraint, the best index to have is compound index which contains all fields that were constrained - in your case it will be index on `(category1, category2, category3, category4, category5)`

However, in practice it is really wasteful to have so many compound indexes. Also, index is only useful if it has high selectivity. For example, if you have field which may have values 0 or 1 with equal probability (selectivity 1/2), it is almost always NOT worth creating index on such a field or even including this field in compound index.

At any rate, always try running EXPLAIN ANALYZE  to get an idea what query planner is thinking and which index it will choose. If you have sequential scan, it may be reason to worry, but not always (for example, using low selectivity index may not be worth it for a planner)

Answer (score 0):

You can analyze what the execution engine will do using ***EXPLAIN EXTENDED query-phrase***. Best case scenario is that MySQL will use an index merge. This means that it will select every option via it's own index, then merge the result sets without any index help. Usually, a composite index is much faster, but that might depend on the number of records and the usage scenario (high or low turnover of records).

Answer (score 0):

As already written by mvp before, use [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) syntax to see how the query optimizer would handle your query. In general mysql uses one index per table you access to fetch the data you are looking for. The optimizer also tries to find the one with the highest selectivity in case there are several indexes possible.

E.g. you might have a query like yours:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE category1=1 AND category2=2 AND category3=3 AND category4=4 AND category5=5
```

It would be possible to use a combined index that contains category1, category2, category3, category4 and category5 or also a combined index that contains only category1 and category2. The optimizer would decide at runtime which one it would take.

Another common example would be:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE category1=1 OR category2=2
```

The query optimizer can only use an index for category1 OR category2 but not both! At least this was what mysql EXPLAIN returned. It might be possible for other databases to run both selections in parallel and simply join the two results and remove duplicates.

Before you start adding lots of indexes remember the overhead they produce. If you have much more read accesses than write accesses it might work out. But if you have also many insert or update operations, the indexes need to be adjusted every time which causes an additional load and increases the query execution time.

For your follow up I recommend this Mysql chapter [How MySQL uses indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html)